# Handling Mixed Object Types in Salesforce Invocable Methods within Record-Triggered Flows

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, salesforce-flow

I'm currently implementing an invocable method in Salesforce, which is intended to be called from a record-triggered flow. The method should be able to handle various types of objects, such as Opportunity, Case, and Custom_Object__c. However, I'm unsure about how Salesforce handles the bulkification of invocable methods in scenarios where the method might receive any object as parameter.

Specifically, if I have record-triggered flows that operates on multiple object types (e.g., Opportunity, Case, Custom_Object__c) and call the same method, is it possible that Salesforce may pass a mix of input of different types in the same method call?

Alternatively, can I rely on the type of the first instance of the list and consider that the rest are of the same type? Or do I need to handle support for all three different object types within the same method call?

I want to ensure proper handling of bulkification and avoid potential design issues or errors in my implementation. Any insights or best practices on how to handle mixed object types within invocable methods in record-triggered flows would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is it possible that Salesforce may pass a mix of input of different types in the same method call?

Yes.

> ...can I rely on the type of the first instance of the list and consider that the rest are of the same type?

No.

> Or do I need to handle support for all three different object types within the same method call?

Yes.

---

As long as the conditions were met for [flow bulkification](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5), the incoming list can be mixed elements. As such, you'll need to keep that in mind when writing your method.

It's likely you'll need to split the incoming data into three lists based on the record type, handle each one separately, then provide any output in the original list order.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. moreover im keen to know if same applies for parallel different transactions as well? initiated via same or different users?

Comment: @JasneetDua Flows do not bulkify across transactions or users. They can only bulkify within the same transaction and only when they meet the conditions in the link I provided in the answer.